# Why does my React component have different css properties when imported to a another component?

Tags: css, reactjs

The component JobList looks great in the HomePage component. Here's how it looks :

[HomePage Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTE8t.png)

And here's the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Main } from './Main'
import JobList from './JobList'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import MainNavbar from './MainNavbar'
import './HomePage.css'

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`

const MainContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <MainNavbar />
      <MainContainer>
        <JobList />
        <Main />
      </MainContainer>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

But when I import the JobList component in the JobDetailsMain component, it looks a lot different.

[JobDetailsMain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKs0j.png)

And here's the code :

```
import React from 'react'
import JobList from '../StartingPage/JobList.jsx'
import MainNavbar from '../StartingPage/MainNavbar.js'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import JobDetails from './JobDetails.jsx'
import './JobDetailsMain.css'

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`

const MainContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`

const JobDetailsMain = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <MainNavbar />
      <MainContainer>
        <JobList />
        <JobDetails />
      </MainContainer>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default JobDetailsMain
```

The CSS files in the components only include a margin and padding set to 0 in the body. Also I did try to make the JobList have a margin left set to 0 in order for it to look similar to the HomePage component but then it increased in width and when I try adjusting the width it starts to cover my main component.

Here's how it looked when I gave it a margin left set to 0:

[Margin Left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8ocU.png)

And the code :

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`

const MainContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`
const JobListContainer = styled.div`
  margin-left: 0;
`

const JobDetailsMain = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <MainNavbar />
      <MainContainer>
        <JobListContainer>
          <JobList />
        </JobListContainer>
        <JobDetails />
      </MainContainer>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

And yeah adjusting the width positions the component somewhere else or covers the JobDetails component. So yeah why is this happening and how do I fix this ?

Heres the code for JobDetailsMain.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show jobdetailsmain.css

Comment: Sure and yeah I just did